# Implementation of a context-free grammar for logical operators with parentheses

Tags: parsing, context-free-grammar, computation-theory, context-free-language

I'm trying to implement a context-free grammar for the language of logical operators with parentheses including operator precedence.

For example, the follows:

```
{1} or {2}
{1} and {2} or {3}
({1} or {2}) and {3}
not {1} and ({2} or {3})
...
```

I've started from the following grammar:

```
expr := control | expr and expr | expr or expr | not expr | (expr)
control := {d+}
```

To implement operator precedence and [eliminate left recursion](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/removing-direct-and-indirect-left-recursion-in-a-grammar/), I changed it in the following way:

```
S ::= expr
expr ::= control or expr1 | expr1
expr1 ::= control and expr2 | expr2
expr2 ::= not expr3 | expr3
expr3 ::= (expr) | expr | control
control := {d+}
```

But such grammar doesn't support examples like: **({1} or {2}) and {3}** that contain 'and' / 'or' after parentheses.

For now, I have the following grammar:

```
S ::= expr
expr ::= control or expr1 | expr1
expr1 ::= control and expr2 | expr2
expr2 ::= not expr3 | expr3
expr3 ::= (expr) | (expr) expr4 | expr | control
expr4 :: = and expr | or expr
control := {d+}
```

Is this grammar correct?
Can it be simplified in some way?

Thanks!

Comment: How do derive your second example from that grammar? I don't think it's possible, in which case the grammar is not correct. An algebraic language with two binary and one unary operator can be written with a total of seven productions (counting alternatives as productions). Yours has 15 or so, so yes  it can be simplified. To start with, there's no need to stitch together a Frankenstein of two different grammar writing styles. I'd start by ditching expr5, 6 and 7.

Comment: Let's say I remove expr5, 6, and 7. In this case, examples like "({1} or {2}) and {3}" don't work.

Comment: You need the production `expr3 -> ( expr )` to get parentheses to work, but you seem to have that. The problem is your use of "control" in the first two productions. Those should instead be left-recursive (although associativity doesn't matter much for boolean operators) and cascading, just like the standard algebraic grammar you'll find all over the internet (for example, [here](http://users.monash.edu/~lloyd/tildeProgLang/Grammar/Arith-Exp/). I chose that one because it's not a PDF unlike the rest of the first two dozen results Google gave me. )

Comment: Thank you @rici, I'll check the example you sent me. Also, I edited my question to have more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement your operator precedence, you want just:

```
S ::= expr
expr ::= expr or expr1 | expr1
expr1 ::= expr1 and expr2 | expr2
expr2 ::= not expr2 | expr3
expr3 ::= (expr) | control
control := {d+}
```

This is left-recursive in order to be left-associative, as that's generally what you want (both for correctness and most parser-generators), but if you need to avoid left recursion for some reason, you can use a right-recursive, right associative grammar:

```
S ::= expr
expr ::= expr1 or expr | expr1
expr1 ::= expr2 and expr1 | expr2
expr2 ::= not expr2 | expr3
expr3 ::= (expr) | control
control := {d+}
```

as both `and` and `or` are associative operators, so left-vs-right doesn't matter.

In both cases, you can "simplify" it by folding expr3 and control into expr2:

```
expr2 ::= not expr2 | ( expr ) | {d+}
```